# Webservice call fails if I dont switch asp.net version back and forth under IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, reporting-services, iis-6, reportingservices-2005

I have the strangest problem.

I've deployed a asp.net mvc webapplication (virtual directory under IIS 6 running under a application pool shared by other net 4.0 applications. In the webapplication I have an assembly that calls the MS Reporting Services webservice. The strange part is, if I dont use the webbapplication for a while and then go into my website so that the call is made to the webservice I get the following exception:

"HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable"

First I thought this had something to do with the service really beeing unavailable but after trying everything from different machines (and console applications) this was not the case.

To make a *looong* error search short: I opened up the properties window for the virtual directory selected the ASP.NET tab, changed the value in the dropdownbox to 2.0.. and **without** clicking apply or ok, change the value back to 4.0 and then clicked "Apply" and then "OK", and voila the service call worked again.

After this procedure is done I've noticed the following log in windows eventlog:

"Restarting W3SVC" with source "ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0". Why is that, I've only choosen the 2.0 framework, and then switched back to 4.0 before hitting the apply button. The asp.net version should still be 4.0 and if any service is restared the source of that event should be 4.0.

If I wait for a while the problem occurs again and I have to do the same procedure again.

Does any one have any idea as to why this happens?

**Update**: The problem was found to be the result of problems doing a DNS lookup. I know it sounds strange but it's true. If we use the ipadress when calling the webservice the problem was solved...

/Best regards Vinblad

Answer (score 0):

Is your application pool being reset? What's its time out I think its about 20 mins by default. By changing the .net version you are recylcing the application pool making it restart.

Comment: Thanks for the response I will look into to that. But should that matter, I mean the webservice call should work regardless if the application pool is restared. If find it strange that the request ends with "Service Unavaiable" when the problem clearly exists on the webserver and not the reporting services server.

Comment: not necessarily. If the app pool restart doesn't complete by time the operation times out then you can have that issue. In fact I was dealing with a similar issue with our code that other week.